# Is it possible to auto click facebook login button(<fb:login-button>)?

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, wordpress

I have read all topics about this problem ([Facebook auto-login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164336/facebook-auto-login), [Auto Facebook Login with Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7302013/auto-facebook-login-with-curl) and etc.). But in none of these I haven't found answer. I have a Wordpress system with FB autoconnect plugin. And I have created facebook app which is showing that wordpress page. I want to make auto log-in to wordpress, when user is logged in facebook. Is it possible? (I tried this one [Auto Login facebook user into application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653427/auto-login-facebook-user-into-application)). But still nothing. I was thinking about auto-click that button with jquery: .click() or trigger('click');, but again nothing. I even tried to check is user logged into facebook, but I don't get any answer.

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
     if (response.status === 'connected') {
          alert('working');
     }
  }
```

. Maybe you have any suggestions? Because I don't know where I can find an answer ...

Comment: Does your JavaScript console show any errors with the JS code you show?